# can't find perl error log

Tags: perl, centos

I have a perl file (eg:test.pl) which does some DB operations.

While testing, its working fine.

I execute this file as a background process by using the command

```
perl test.pl &
```

Its working properly for some days.

But after some days ,the file execution get stopped.

How can I find the reason or view the error?

I checked the log file  "/var/log/httpd/error_log", but can't find anything.

I keep the perl file in a server, which runs in Cent OS.

Any one have idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### There is no 'perl error log'

But you can define a destination for output to be saved to, just run your script like this:

```
perl test.pl >> /var/log/some-log-file.log 2>&1 &
```

This will redirect `STDOUT` (normal shell output) and `STDERR` (error output) to `/var/log/some-log-file.log` instead of to the terminal.

You may also wish to use `nohup` in order to have the script ignore `HANGUP` (logout) signals, which could be causing your unexpected terminations:

```
nohup perl test.pl >> /var/log/some-log-file.log 2>&1 &
```

Obviously, whichever user you run the script as will need to have write access to the log file.

Comment: ,Thanks for your response. let me do like that.I just want to inform you that i run this file from the terminal only and  not from the web

Comment: @Linto These are terminal (`bash`) commands. What I'm saying is, your user will need to be able to write to whatever file you specify, so you'll have to check permissions.

Comment: actually i execute this file as a back ground process by  Root user.So i think there won't be any permission issue

Comment: "i think there won't be any permission issue" - just a huge potential security hole :-)

Comment: @Linto You shouldn't run anything as root unless you absolutely need to.